# Send array from javascript to Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, spring

I have a javascript function that makes a post to a controller API. Here´s the code:

```
exports.importList = function (req, res) {
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var agencyId = req.user.agency_id;
var userId = req.user.id;
 data = {
id_list: req.body.ids,
remoteHost:'127.0.0.1',
userId : userId,
agencyId:agencyId
};

call = '/ilist/importer/list/'; //Spring route

fetcher.post(call, 'post', data, function (err, result) {
    console.log(data);
})
}
```

`req.body.ids` is an array of string values, so the data I want to send to my Controller has this structure:

```
{ id_list: [ '2147041', '2155271' ], 
  remoteHost: '127.0.0.1', 
  userId: 'user', 
  agencyId: 1 }
```

My controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list/", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody RemaxResponse importPropertyList(@RequestBody ArrayList<String> data )  {

    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String id : data.id_list) {
        ids.add(Long.valueOf(id));
   }

       response = ilistIImporterService.importPropertyList(ids);
    return response;
}
```

I need to take in my Controller the array of strings and store it in an array of integer, and the other parameters store in integer variables.
Now, I'm getting that the data I send from javascript is sintactically incorrect. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: `req.body.ids` is an object, `req.body.ids.id_list` is an array, no? You also shouldn't need to use `@RequestBody List<String>`, spring should parse that correctly if you use `@RequestBody List<Long>` directly

Comment: But what about the other keys in data, like: userId,...? How can I get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send the whole object, I'd create a pojo and use that as `@RequestBody` like

```
public @ResponseBody RemaxResponse importPropertyList(@RequestBody RequestObject data )  {
```

Now spring can parse the whole data nicely to the given pojo, and you can simply use the `getters` to obtain the data you need.

A pojo could look like

```
public class RequestObject {
    private List<Long> idList = null;
    private String remoteHost;
    private String userId;
    private Integer agencyId;

    public List<Long> getIdList() {
        return idList;
    }

    public void setIdList(List<Long> idList) {
        this.idList = idList;
    }

    public String getRemoteHost() {
        return remoteHost;
    }

    public void setRemoteHost(String remoteHost) {
        this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Integer getAgencyId() {
        return agencyId;
    }

    public void setAgencyId(Integer agencyId) {
        this.agencyId = agencyId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but isn´t there another way of doing this, I think is a waste of code, since I won´t use it any more, just in this case....

Comment: You could also just use a `Map<String, Object>` as `@RequestBody` - but then you'll need to parse everything to the correct type. The cleaner way is the pojo, the Map would be faster to write though.. @YanetPedraza